# Chainlink job is not being called by the Solidity Smart Contract using Operator.sol contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink, kovan

The job spec deployed and running on Chainlink node is being successfully triggered and completed when called using the Solidity smart contract that is using the `Oracle.sol` contract.

But, since the requirement is to return the large response (https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/), so I have to use `Operator.sol` contract instead of `Oracle.sol`. Then, the job is not being called.

The deployed Operator contract is looking as:

[image: Deployed Operator.sol]

---

The LINK Token and Owner addresses that I have used to deploy the `Operator.sol` contract are:

[image: LINK and Owner addresses]

---

The LINK Token address is basically taken from the official Chainlink doc (https://docs.chain.link/docs/fulfilling-requests/) mentioning the Kovan Testnet LINK token address:

[image: LINK Token address]

---

And the owner address is taken from the Account address of the running Chainlink node:

[image: Owner address]

---

And the Solidity smart contract code is:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract GenericLargeResponse is ChainlinkClient {
  using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

  bytes public data;

  constructor(
  ) {
    setChainlinkToken(0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088);
    setChainlinkOracle(0x8114f13FaF377FFc7A5AD32fb8a1e448667b871D);
  }

  function requestBytes(
  )
    public
  {
    bytes32 specId = "a3d1b2c945244e44bdb412c5b5287df3";
    uint256 payment = 100000000000000000;
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(specId, address(this), this.fulfillBytes.selector);
    req.add("data", "{\"agg_x\": \"agg_mean\", \"dataset_code\":\"MODIS/006/MOD14A1\", \"selected_band\":\"MaxFRP\", \"image_scale\":1000, \"start_date\":\"2021-09-01\", \"end_date\":\"2021-09-10\", \"geometry\":{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"id\":1},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[29.53125,19.642587534013032],[29.53125,27.059125784374068],[39.90234375,27.059125784374068],[39.90234375,19.642587534013032],[29.53125,19.642587534013032]]]}},{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"id\":2},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[46.40625,13.752724664396988],[46.40625,20.138470312451155],[56.25,20.138470312451155],[56.25,13.752724664396988],[46.40625,13.752724664396988]]]}}]}}");
       
    sendOperatorRequest(req, payment);
  }

  function fulfillBytes(
    bytes32 requestId,
    bytes memory bytesData
  )
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId)
  {
    data = bytesData;
  }

}
```

The contract is compiled and deployed successfully. But the `requestBytes` function is unable to trigger the job-spec running on the Chainlink node.

PS: The function of the similar smart contract that is using the `Oracle.sol` is successfully triggering the job-spec.

---

The TOML Job spec running on Chainlink node is:

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "shamba-fire-data"
contractAddress = "0x8114f13FaF377FFc7A5AD32fb8a1e448667b871D"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="bridge" name="shamba-fire-bridge" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\":$(decode_cbor.data)}"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="result,1,0" data="$(fetch)"]
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(uint256 value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0x8114f13FaF377FFc7A5AD32fb8a1e448667b871D" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
externalJobID = "a3d1b2c9-4524-4e44-bdb4-12c5b5287df3"
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, like what I'm doing wrong in these steps due to which the smart contract is unable to trigger the job-spec ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the owner address of the `Operator.sol` should be the Metamask wallet Kovan testnet address (instead of the account address of the running Chainlink node) from which the transactions are being done.

Then, after the `Operator.sol` being deployed successfully, call the `setAuthorizedSenders` function of the `Operator.sol` by passing in the account address of the running Chainlink node in the senders `address[]` field like:

[image: setAuthorizedSenders function]

---

Then, the job-spec's `encode_data` should be having `requestId`parameter as well:

```
encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(bytes32 requestId, uint256[][] value)" data="{ \\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
```

The entire job-spec should be:

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "shamba-fire-data"
contractAddress = "0xf4434feDd55D3d6573627F39fA39867b23f4Bf7F"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="bridge" name="shamba-fire-bridge" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\":$(decode_cbor.data)}"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="result" data="$(fetch)"]
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(bytes32 requestId, uint256[][] value)" data="{ \\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0xf4434feDd55D3d6573627F39fA39867b23f4Bf7F" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
externalJobID = "66229880-79e1-43c6-9d9e-0eb4b668729d"
```

---

Similarly, the solidity smart contract code should be:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract GenericLargeResponse is ChainlinkClient {
  using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

  uint256[][] public data;

  constructor(
  ) {
    setChainlinkToken(0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088);
    setChainlinkOracle(0xf4434feDd55D3d6573627F39fA39867b23f4Bf7F);
  }

  function requestBytes(
  )
    public
  {
    bytes32 specId = "6622988079e143c69d9e0eb4b668729d";
    //0x3065666666656632313564353466316339663332623636376466613061346536;
    uint256 payment = 1000000000000000000;
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(specId, address(this), this.fulfillBytes.selector);
    req.add("data", "{\"agg_x\": \"agg_mean\", \"dataset_code\":\"MODIS/006/MOD14A1\", \"selected_band\":\"MaxFRP\", \"image_scale\":1000, \"start_date\":\"2021-09-01\", \"end_date\":\"2021-09-10\", \"geometry\":{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"id\":1},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[29.53125,19.642587534013032],[29.53125,27.059125784374068],[39.90234375,27.059125784374068],[39.90234375,19.642587534013032],[29.53125,19.642587534013032]]]}},{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"id\":2},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[46.40625,13.752724664396988],[46.40625,20.138470312451155],[56.25,20.138470312451155],[56.25,13.752724664396988],[46.40625,13.752724664396988]]]}}]}}");
       
    sendOperatorRequest(req, payment);
  }

  function fulfillBytes(
    bytes32 requestId,
    uint256[][] memory bytesData
  )
    public
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId)
  {
    data = bytesData;
  }

}
```